# Do we say that an $m \times n$ matrix A exists in $\mathbb{R}^m$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: matrices, functions

As per the title,

Do we say that an $m \times n$ matrix A exists in $\mathbb{R}^m$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Neither -- it exists in $\mathbb R^{mn}$. The dimension $mn$ is just the number of entries in the matrix -- literally $m\times n$.

Comment: And an nxn matrix doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$ either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

Usually, we use the notation $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Although it is Clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$.

Comment: Thanks for that

Comment: However, $\ \mathbb R^{\{1..5\}\times\{1..9\}}\ $ is truly different from $\ \mathbb R^{\{1..3\}\times\{1..15\}}.$

Comment: They are isomorphic as additive groups tho

Comment: @hlcrypto123 Techincally, all $\Bbb R$-vector spaces $V$ such that $1\le \dim_{\Bbb R}V\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ are isomorphic as additive groups.

Comment: @Gae.S. how are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic then?

Comment: @hlcrypto123 As $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces, and moreso as abelian groups, $\Bbb R\simeq \Bbb Q^{(\beth_1)}$ and $\Bbb R^2\simeq \Bbb Q^{(\beth_1)}\times \Bbb Q^{(\beth_1)}\simeq\Bbb Q^{(\beth_1+\beth_1)}=\Bbb Q^{(\beth_1)}$.